# Using a Projection in place of Find() in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

Relatively new to MVC and LINQ.

Using built-in methods with LINQ/EF do not generally work for me because I' need to use multiple tables and create a projection to a new type to get the data I need.

When returning an iEnumerable, I am able to do this without a problem.  My view is expecting an iEnumerable and my LINQ query provided just that.

However, when I try to replace the Find() method to return a single record, I'm running into a problem.

My projection is identical to the one that returns multiple records but I have added a where clause to limit the return to a single record (using a unique ID).

I've changed my view to expect and object of the type I'm projecting to but that is as far as I can get.

If I just return the query as is, deferred execution causes a problem in that I'm actually passing the query to my view, not the results (as expected).

So I'm trying to figure out how to (I guess) execute the query and get the object in my controller and then pass that to the view.  I've tried SingleOrDefault() and the like to 'force' execution but that generates a new exception (Unable to create a constant value of type 'System.Object'. Only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context.)

Clearly I don't understand something that is going on here.

```
        var model =
            (from p in db.t_Protocol
            join pt in db.t_ProtocolType on p.ProtocolTypeId equals pt.ProtocolTypeID
            where p.ProtocolId.Equals(id)
            select new ProtocolView
            {
                ProtocolId = p.ProtocolId,
                Protocol = p.Protocol,
                ProtocolType = pt.ProtocolType,
                IsAdmission = p.IsAdmission,
                IsReleased = p.IsReleased
            })
            ;
```

My view is expecting:
    @model ECM.Models.ProtocolView

Comment: add .First() on the of the query

Comment: You seem to have 2 issues here. Use `FirstOrDefault` to get a single record. If you get an exception, then something is wrong with your query - most likely the `p.ProtocolId.Equals(id)` condition. Try replacing it with `p.ProtocolId == iid`.

Comment: The problem was the where clause (`p.ProtocolId.Equals(id)`) apparently does something different that the == operator.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

First of all by stating your view is expecting `@model ECM.Models.ProtocolView` states that the view is only expecting a single record. If when setting your Var model the child table has more than 1 record then your projection will force n number of records into model regardless of the parent only having 1 record. for your view to expect an IEnumerable you need to change your view declaration to be `@model IEnmerable<ECM.Models.ProtocolView>` Also if you really need to perform a Find use IQueryable first them return the result as IEnumerable since the payload on Ienumerable is smaller than IQueryable

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  As my original post states, my view is expecting a single object.  The solution was posted above.